# android MediaSession setActive(false) not work

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use `MediaSession` to respond to headset media buttons, and want to stop the sound when activity is paused. **I also want to make the headset media buttons not active when activity is paused.**

From the android documentation, it said the `setActive` method is use to **"set if this session is currently active and ready to receive commands"**. But it not worked, I can still use head resume the music when activity is paused. Do I misunderstand the function of this method?

My code is as followed:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSession
private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lapple)
    mediaPlayer?.isLooping = true
    mediaPlayer?.start()
    // Create a MediaSessionCompat

    mediaSession = MediaSession(this, "test_log").apply {

        // Enable callbacks from MediaButtons and TransportControls
        setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)

        // Do not let MediaButtons restart the player when the app is not visible
        setMediaButtonReceiver(null)

        // Set an initial PlaybackState with ACTION_PLAY, so media buttons can start the player
        val stateBuilder = PlaybackState.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY or PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE or PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
        setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build())

        // MySessionCallback has methods that handle callbacks from a media controller
        setCallback(object : MediaSession.Callback() {
            override fun onPlay() {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "${this@MainActivity.hashCode()}: onPlay",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                mediaPlayer?.start()
            }

            override fun onPause() {
                mediaPlayer?.pause()
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "${this@MainActivity.hashCode()}: onPause",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }

        })
    }

    mediaSession.isActive = true

    //mediaController = MediaController(this, mediaSession.sessionToken)

}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mediaSession.isActive = false
    mediaPlayer?.pause()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mediaSession.isActive = true
    mediaPlayer?.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    mediaPlayer?.release()
    super.onDestroy()
}

fun newActivity(view: View) {
    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession#release()) says:

> Set if this session is currently active and ready to receive commands. If set to false your session's controller may not be discoverable. You must set the session to active before it can start receiving media button events or transport commands.

It does not say that you should set it to false to stop receiving commands. I guess if the controller is already discovered, the value doesn't matter anymore.

So instead you should use `release` or `setCallback(null)` according to this documentation.

Comment: What if I have two activities, both has a MediaSession, and I want to make the MediaSession of first activity not active. The only way is to release the MediaSession?

Comment: Documentation says you should rather use one session with a service which is shared between the activities

Comment: no no , the two activities do not play the same music, so it cannot be shared

Comment: You could either share the player and switch the track on activity switch, or otherwise work with the setCallback as mentioned above, if you that is set to null, you will not receive the callbacks for that mediasession...

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: For me `setCallback(null)` was not working, since I by mistake added two `MEDIA_BUTTON.BroadcastReceiver` to `Manifest.xml`. This somehow started the `Service` in the background without attached `Activity`

```
 <application>

        <service
            android:name=".service.MyService">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>

        <!-- this was the stupid receiver. DO NOT DO IT ;-) -->
        <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```